# FontAwesome Icon Inside Input button using :after

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I am trying to have a calendar icon to show on a submit button.
Note: i cannot insert a  tag or anything similar- I simply want to format the  button from css. So far nothing shows.

the HTML code is:

```
<p class="mphb_sc_search-submit-button-wrapper">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search">
</p>
```

The css code is:

```
.mphb_sc_search-submit-button-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative
}

.mphb_sc_search-submit-button-wrapper:after {
    content: '\f274';
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

`
UPDATE: 
I have to change the color to white so it now shows.

[image]

I was looking for something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you loaded font awesome in your page?

Comment: I know that this one works on other pages- so the font must be uploaded:

    `<button type="submit" class="external_bookingbutton">
Check Availability 
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</button>`

Comment: The code you posted appears to work when font awesome is loaded. There must be something else in your page, not included here, which prevents it from working as expected. Without access to that something or to a [mcve] featuring the bug, the chances of anyone being able to help converge to `null`.

Comment: color: white; 
    right: 100px!important;
    top:35px!important;

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the font awesome file

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css 

.mphb_sc_search-submit-button-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;

}
.mphb_sc_search-submit-button-wrapper input{
  padding-right:30px;
}
.mphb_sc_search-submit-button-wrapper:after {
    content: '\f274';
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top:3px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9jngfrm5/